# Can i have my own given when then implementation in Karate for my own keywords?

Tags: karate

Karate is a great testing framework but in some senarios we may need to write our own Given when then implementations and own key words in combitionation in the karate provided one like

Feature File :::

Feature: API Test
@SmokeTests @RegressionTests
Scenario Outline: get user details
Given url urlPath
And path '30'
And Check Is The Project Live
When method 
Then status 200
* def name = response.name
* print 'Ankush Test is this'
* match name == 'Chidambar Nayar'
Examples:
| METHOD |
| GET    |

Java Code

```
@And("Is The Project Live")
public void liveCheck(){
    System.out.println("Is The Project Live");
}
```

Just for one line we have a some implementation is this possible.

And I am not looking for Java Interop as a solution here

Comment: short answer is no. linked q & a goes into details